# Theme.of(context) not passed to simpleDialog

Tags: flutter

I'm using a showDialog function in my app. The themeData is not passed from my parent widget to my showDialog. Can anyone tell me why it's not working? I have to specify the theme is working everywhere else **but not** in my showDialog. I'm using provider to change the theme accordingly to dark and light. Anyways, in the code just below the showDialog it works.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Cart cartProvider = Provider.of<Cart>(context);
    Future<Future> showDialogFunction(BuildContext context) {
      // showing basket cart
      return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          Widget cartDialog = BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
              child: SimpleDialog(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                children: [
                  Consumer<Cart>(builder: (context, cart, child) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 1.sh,
                      width: 0.8.sw,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
                                color: mainSecondaryColor,
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                },
                              ),
                              Text('Cosul meu',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary)),
```

My main.dart file:

```
class FinerApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => ThemeNotifier(),
        child: ScreenUtilInit(
            designSize: Size(360, 690),
            allowFontScaling: true,
            builder: () => Consumer<ThemeNotifier>(
                    builder: (context, ThemeNotifier notifier, child) {
                  return Provider<AuthBase>(
                    create: (context) => Auth(),
                    child: MaterialApp(
                      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                      title: 'Flutter_ScreenUtil',
                      home: MaterialApp(
                        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                        theme: notifier.darkTheme
                            ? CustomTheme.darkTheme
                            : CustomTheme.lightTheme,
                        home: LandingPage(),
                        routes: routes,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                })));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're not using the `context` which is given by the `build` method. Change the variable name of your `build` method like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext buildContext) {...}
```

And then use

```dart
Theme.of(buildContext).textTheme.caption)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! You saved me. But can you explain me why that happens?

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, you need to use the `context` you're receiving from the `build` method. When you use a `Builder` or `Consumer`, they introduce a new `BuildContext` which has its own default theme.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Theme like this
declare theme in MaterialApp

```
MaterialApp(
  title: appName,
  theme: ThemeData(
    // Define the default brightness and colors.
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue[800],
    accentColor: Colors.cyan[600],

    // Define the default font family.
    fontFamily: 'Georgia',

    // Define the default TextTheme. Use this to specify the default
    // text styling for headlines, titles, bodies of text, and more.
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 72.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      headline6: TextStyle(fontSize: 36.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
      bodyText2: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontFamily: 'Hind'),
    ),
  ),
  home: MyHomePage(
    title: appName,
  ),
);
```

use the theme likethis

```
Container(
  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
  child: Text(
    'Text with a background color',
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
  ),
),
```

find more here:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes#using-a-theme

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry I completed my question with some code. As I said, the theme is working just below, but in the simpleDialog isn't. The debug console is empty aswell.